# Eclipse static web project HTTP Preview/Server module conflicts with relative paths

Tags: html, css, eclipse, web

So I start a static web project on eclipse. Let's say MySite. And then I start a jetty web server on eclipse and open localhost:8080 on my browser.

This is what I'll see:

[image: Main HTTP Preview Page]

So I go to `localhost:8080/MySite/index.html` and see my homepage.

[image: Home Page]

As you can see the the link is not leading where it should be.
It should be going to `localhost:8080/MySite/index.html`, or even more preferable, MySite's index page should be hosted on `localhost:8080/index.html` and not on some module.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I were to change this to MySite/index.html it defeats the purpose of it being an http preview server, because MySite will eventually be it's own site and not some kind of module.

How to fix this without using a workaround?

Comment: If I can get an explanation of how to use the jetty plugin using only default files that I can exclude, that would be nice too.

Comment: What do you get if you access "http://localhost:8080/MySite/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to the conclusion that Eclipse is so java-oriented that for static websites I need to use atom instead.

Atom has platform-ide-terminal so I can generate static websites.
It also has atom-live-server, although atom-live-server.js needs to be tweaked
like so: https://www.diffchecker.com/JD1o1fvy

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see the the link is not leading where it should be. It should be going to localhost:8080/MySite/index.html, but instead it goes to localhost:8080/index.html

That is because you are using a url form that is relative to server's root `/`.

Simply use a `./`(page-relative path) instead of `/`(server-root-relative path) in `MySite/index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `./`is page-relative path, not app-relative path, so if the app has any folders, which it does, then it doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, `./` would be page-relative(updated in answer). But even if your app has folders, can't you simply give the path relative to app-root(`../static/foo.css` and `../static/bar.js`) ?

Comment: No, not when it's an extended base page.

Comment: I changed the question a bit, because I'm more hoping of an answer that gets rid of having to use a module name.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i have worked with tomcat Server with Eclipse , hope this will help .

Have you mentioned your landing page in WEB.xml file . if you have not added your landing page in you web.xml file like the below than add this and try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Your Website</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```